# JtaTransactionManager EntityInterceptor Prototype Spring/Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jta

We upgrade our application from Spring 3.2.13.RELEASE/Hibernate 3.5.6-Final to Spring 4.3.6.RELEASE/Hibernate 4.2.20.Final-redhat-1. 
In Hibernate 3 we had the HibernateInterceptor, which had a nice functionality. 
We used this interceptor to set our EntityInterceptor(Prototype) by opening a new session.

```
<bean id="hibernateInterceptor" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
    </property>
    <property name="entityInterceptorBeanName">
        <value>entityInterceptorName</value> <!--set with BeanFactory  -->
    </property>
</bean> 
<bean id="entityInterceptorName" class="..." scope="prototype" />
```

There isn't any equivalent class in Spring/Hibernate 4.  
We know, that the HibernateTransactionManager have a functionality like that, but there no way to set it in the JtaTransactionManager (What we actually use). 
Is there any reason, why these Transactionmanagers are functionality different? 
Is there any other way to use an Entityinterceptor like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found two workarounds. 
One of them is to define the hibernate.current_session_context_class with our Class on the SessionFactory. Our class set the our implementation of the JTASessionContext.

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
          *
        <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.path.to.my.context.MySpringSessionContext</prop>
          *
      </props>
 </property>
```

Own sessioncontext:

```
public class MySpringSessionContext extends SpringSessionContext {


    public MySpringSessionContext(SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
         super(sessionFactory);
         Field transactionManager = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("transactionManager");
         transactionManager.setAccessible(true);
         Object value = transactionManager.get(this);

         if (value != null) {
             Field jtaSessionContext = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("jtaSessionContext");
             jtaSessionContext.setAccessible(true);
             jtaSessionContext.set(this, new MySpringJtaSessionContext(sessionFactory));
           }
   }
}
```

Own JTASessionContext:

```
public class MySpringJtaSessionContext extends SpringJtaSessionContext {

      private BeanFactory beanFactory;
      private String entityInterceptor;

      public MySpringJtaSessionContext(SessionFactoryImplementor factory) {
            super(factory);
            //Ugly but we need Spring
            Interceptor interceptor = factory.getInterceptor();
            if(interceptor instanceof MyBeanFactoryInterceptor){
                this.beanFactory = ((MyBeanFactoryInterceptor) interceptor).getBeanFactory();
                this.entityInterceptor = ((MyBeanFactoryInterceptor) interceptor).getEntityInterceptorBeanName();
            }
       }

       @Override
       protected SessionBuilder baseSessionBuilder() {
          return super.baseSessionBuilder().interceptor(getEntityInterceptor());

      }

    public Interceptor getEntityInterceptor() throws IllegalStateException, BeansException {
           if (this.beanFactory == null) {
              return EmptyInterceptor.INSTANCE;
           }
           return this.beanFactory.getBean((String) this.entityInterceptor, Interceptor.class);
     }
}
```

The other workaround: use the OpenSessionInterceptor (override), but there some other difficulties.(Flush, close session) But like:

Open session with entityinterceptor:

```
@Override
protected Session openSession() {
    try {
        Session session = getSessionFactory().withOptions().interceptor(getEntityInterceptor()).openSession();
        if (TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly()) {
            session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
        } else {
            session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.AUTO);
        }
        return session;
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        throw new DataAccessResourceFailureException("Could not open Hibernate Session", ex);
    }
}
```

Get interceptor from Spring:

```
public Interceptor getEntityInterceptor() throws IllegalStateException, BeansException {
    if (this.entityInterceptor instanceof String) {
        if (this.beanFactory == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot get entity interceptor via bean name if no bean factory set");
        }
        return this.beanFactory.getBean((String) this.entityInterceptor, Interceptor.class);
    }
    return (Interceptor) this.entityInterceptor;
}
```